# Как с помощью JavaScript (JS) изменять текстовое содержимое HTML-тега при клике по нему

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, input, trello

Предположим у меня на странице есть какой-то текстовый блок:

```
<p>Letter wooded direct two men indeed income sister.</p>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при клике по нему, пользователь мог начать редактировать его текстовое содержимое?

Что-то похоже реализовано в Trello при попытке изменить заголовок задачи или ее описание. Такая штука есть еще в редакторе шаблона WordPress - наглядная демонстрация [в этом фрагменте видео](https://youtu.be/mLg1HJJFzeM?t=435).

Если знаете какие-нибудь библиотеки реализующие это, то буду благодарен, если вы о них расскажете. Но в первую очередь меня интересует принцип, того как это реализуется.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content

Comment: Плюс еще можно использовать `window.getSelection()` для получения выделенной подстроки, содержание которой можно помещать в элемент, разбивать остальное пространство на два `TextNode` и вклинивать между ними новый элемент. Или просто возвращать измененное содержимое одной строкой в качестве `innerHTML`. Это для эффектов вроде жирный, курсив, разбивку на параграфы, вставку ссылки и т.д.

Comment: @Leonid спасибо